# oauth2 with additional secret

Tags: encryption, authentication, oauth2

I'm using Spring boot to create an application that stores user secrets in a database (**I have to store the secrets**); each secret is stored in the database after being encrypted with the user's password (I don't use the password directly, I use a hashing function like kerberos' `stringtokey` (just for example)).

As the first attempt for the signup, I decided to let the user authenticate with oauth2 and afterwards, ask for an additional password (to use to encrypt the secret).

What do you think?

I would like to avoid using an additional password, but if the user logs in with oauth2, for example, with a Google password, how can I derive a key from that password (and use it to encrypt the secret) if I can't get it?

Comment: This is looking like a programming question and not a security question.

Comment: I know you were told to ask here, but really, the StackOverflow people should have moved it here instead of you asking twice.

Comment: If the secret is stored encrypted by a key derived from the user's password, why is the secret being stored on the server at all, and also when does the secret actually get used (e.g. is it only when the user is logged in, or at other times)? Are you just trying to protect the secrets at rest in the event that the server gets compromised? Or are you trying to do end-to-end encryption where the server never sees the secrets at all?

Comment: the secret is something that user can't easy remember (a random string of 60+ chars). so the user create a easy-to-remember password to encrypt this secret in a way that he can use it in the future, while is logged, without reinsert the secret every time. is not required to be end-to-end, this is what i want to do: "protect the secrets at rest in the event that the server gets compromised"